# jQuery plugin with success and failure callbacks

Tags: jquery

I wrote this plugin, which I use often, I like it because most of the time I'm only checking if `true`. However I've just come across a need to know whether the result is `false`.

I think I want a `success` and `failure` callback inside the function, but I can't figure out how to return it. Deferred and promises are busting a brain cell right now.

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(fn) {
    if (this.length > 0) {
        var f = arguments[0];
        arguments[0] = function(e) {
            f(e);
        }
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
        return fn ? this.bind(name, fn) : this.trigger(name);
    } else {
        return this.length > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no async code here, so you can just take two functions as parameters of your plugin and call them as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide an example it would be useful, the purpose of what this plugins does and what your end result will be is a bit unclear to me.

BUT, i do know promises, take look below.

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(fn) {
    var deferredObj = jQuery.Deferred();
    if (this.length > 0) {
        var f = arguments[0];
        arguments[0] = function(e) {
            f(e);
        }
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
        if(fn) {  this.bind(name, fn) 
        } else {  this.trigger(name)} ;
        deferredObj.resolve( "some success value" );
    } else {
        deferredObj.reject( "Length is not greater then 0" );
    }
    return deferredObj.promise;
}
```

The code snippet you have added has no **async** operations so i see no profit in using promises what so ever, a simple return boolean would suffice.

A codepen example might help clearify what you problem is.